# How to parse raw data in android kotlin using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a webservice api which is having some raw data. No json structure data. And all i want to parse it. This is the response i am getting from an api.
[image]

And here is my implementation for calling the api.
[image]
the above implementation gives me this error, can you please help in this.
[image]

Comment: If possible change the API response to JSON . if not there is no way to parse it because its not a format its just some random string . return `ResponseBody` from the API call then get the String response from body then you can use it .

Comment: If your backend service returns text/plain response you could add [ScalarsConverter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) before GsonConverter.

Comment: @Sky yes i have done that, and it's working. Thanks

Comment: Do not post images of text

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around and from the last comment above, i have resolved the issue. Here is the result.

If you have non json structure in api response, you just need to replace the GsonConverterFacroty line from the retrofit client i.e

```
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

with

```
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

and that's all. You can add both if you have mix responses i.e json and non-json.